# How do you Efficiently Multiply a Numpy Vector by an Array of Numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

If I have an array of values:

```
numbers = np.array([1, 2, 4, 5])
```

and a vector:

```
vector = np.array([1, 0, 1])
```

How do I multiply the vector by the value array to get the following:

```
vector_array = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [4, 0, 4], [5, 0, 5]])
```

I have tried to do this using matmul by doing the following:

```
vector_array = vector[..., None]@numbers
```

and:

```
vector_array = vector.T@numbers
```

I expect to get column vectors which I can then transpose, however instead I get this output:

Option 1:

```
vector_array = vector[..., None]@numbers
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

Option 2:

```
vector_array = vector.T@numbers
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 3)
```

How can I force matmul to behave in the expected way and multiply the column vector by the row vector to give me a matrix? Is there another function I should be using?

Comment: In your mind, what's the difference between an array of numbers and a vector.  Both are 1d numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [numpy broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
vector_array = vector * numbers[:, None]
```

Output:

```
>>> vector_array
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [4, 0, 4],
       [5, 0, 5]])
```

To understand it, look at `numbers[:, None]`:

```
>>> numbers
array([1, 2, 4, 5])

>>> numbers[:, None]
array([[1],
       [2],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

So basically `vector * numbers[:, None]` multiplies `vector` by each element of `numbers`.

Comment: How does this compare, speed wise, to a built in function like numpy.outer?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm guessing this is faster but I'll run some benchmarks.

Comment: (by the way, numpy broadcasting _is_ builtin, because it's not a Python feature, it's a numpy feature.)

Comment: @Connor My benchmarks indicate that for small amounts of data, mine is a bit faster, and for larger data, ours are about the same.

Comment: Thanks so much! I would give you a second upvote if I could!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility different from the one given by @richardec is to use `numpy.outer`:

```
numpy.outer(numbers, normal) = np.array([[1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [4, 0, 4], [5, 0, 5]])
```

as required. However, I am not sure which method is faster.

Comment: `outer` is more focused; while the broadcasted approach can be used with other operators.  Many of the `ufunc`, (e.g. `np.add`) have an `outer` method that does the same thing.  Overall I don't think speed differences are significant.